# Entity Framework's FromSql method to execute a SQL Server table-valued function that uses an inner join select statement

Tags: entity-framework, user-defined-functions

[Output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqqpH.png)

I created the entity class to match the function columns, included the DbSet in the context class, and completed the method in the repository, but the function call using FromSql is not working.

Here's the code:

1. SQL Server function:

   ```
    CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufn_viewInvoices()
    RETURN TABLE
    AS
        RETURN 
            (SELECT 
                 i.InvoiceId, i.CustomerId, c.CompanyName, 
                 c.LastName, a.StreetNumber, a.StreetName, 
                 a.City, i.Revenue, i.DateStarted, i.DateCompleted, 
                 i.DaysEstimate, i.DaysActual
             FROM 
                 Invoices i, Customers c, Addresses a 
             WHERE 
                 i.CustomerId = c.CustomerId 
                 AND i.WorkAddressId = a.AddressId);
   ```
2. My entity class to match the columns in the function's select statement:

   ```
    public class InvoiceCustomerNameAddresses
    {
        [Key] 
        public byte InvoiceId { get; set; }
        public byte CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string StreetNumber { get; set; }
        public string StretName { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public decimal? Revenue { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateStarted { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateCompleted { get; set; }
        public byte? DaysEstimate { get; set; }
        public byte? DaysActual { get; set; }
    }
   ```
3. The `DbSet` in the `DbContext` class:

   ```
    public  DbSet<InvoiceCustomerNameAddresses> InvoiceCustomerNameAddresses { get; set; }
   ```
4. This is the method in the repository:

   ```
    public List<InvoiceCustomerNameAddresses> GetInvoicesUsingTVF()
    {
        List<InvoiceCustomerNameAddresses> invoicesList;

        try 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Inside GetInvoicesUsingTVF method in repo, about to call function");

            invoicesList = context.InvoiceCustomerNameAddresses.FromSql("SELECT * FROM 
                           [dbo].ufn_viewInvoices()").ToList();

            Console.WriteLine("Function called, invoicesList count: " + invoicesList.Count);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In repo's catch, so something went wrong");
            invoicesList = null;
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred");
        }
        return invoicesList;
    }
   ```
5. Method in controller:

   ```
    [HttpGet]
    public List<InvoiceCustomerNameAddresses> GetAllInvoicesUsingTVF() 
    {
        List<InvoiceCustomerNameAddresses> detailedInvoicesList = null;
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Inside controller, about to call the repo's getInvoicesUsingTVF method");
            detailedInvoicesList = invoiceRepository.GetInvoicesUsingTVF();
            Console.WriteLine("Received detailedInvoicesList, count: " + detailedInvoicesList.Count);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In catch block, so something went wrong");
            detailedInvoicesList = null;
        }   

        return detailedInvoicesList;
    }
   ```

Please note:

- Console printout statements in the code above, before and after the function call with `.FromSql` method: the first console printout got executed, but there's an obvious problem with the function call statement execution because the next console printout that gets executed is the one in the catch block.
- Note in the output shown in the screenshot the line that says "Executing ObjectResult, writing   value of type 'null'". This reflects the statement in the catch block: "invoicesLIst = null" (see picture attached).
- Note that this function call does not use parameters, and lastly, executing this function from SQL Server Management Studio works perfectly fine.

**Question**: what am I missing that my function call with the `.FromSql` is not working?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Thank you, @marc_s.  I changed my function to use JOIN instead.  As to my question, can you think of any reason why the .FromSql method is not working?

Comment: You should **inspect** the exception you're getting! Most likely, it will tell you what's wrong and possibly what to do to fix it! Don't just report "an error occurred" - output the information contained in the exception! That's what it's there for!

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not really getting an error, just 'undefined', but that's because I set up the code that way.  Anyway, I figured it out.  I misspelled StreetName (had StretName instead) in the entity class, and the entity's property names must match the column names in the select statement in the Sql Server function.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this question because after a while, the obvious does not seem so obvious and an extra pair of eyes could maybe help in seeing what I was missing. I was not getting an exception but was not getting the data I expected (screenshot of output attached) because I had a misspelling mistake. The properties in the entity class MUST match the column names of the select statement in the function being called with the EF's FromSql method. Therefore, 'StretName' in the code above for the entity is not recognized; it should be 'StreetName' instead. It works perfectly fine now.